# show that a set $\{1, 1 + X, (1 + X)^2 , . . . , (1 + X)^n \}$ is a basis for $\Bbb{R}_n [X]$.

Tags: linear-algebra

> I have to show that the set $$\{1, 1 + X, (1 + X)^2 , . . . , (1 + X)^n \}$$ is a basis
>   for $\Bbb{R}_n [X]$, where $\Bbb{R}_n [X]$ denotes the vectorspace of all polynomials of degree less than or equal to $n$ over $\Bbb{R}$.

I guess I need to show that its spanning set and linear independent

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use MathJax to write your formulae. What is $R n [X]$?

Comment: @tomjoe: Do you mean $\{1,1+x,(1+x)^2,\cdots,(1+x)^n\}$ ?

Comment: Yes that is correct -polynomial

Comment: Fine! What is $R_n[x]$ ? Do you mean the vectorspace of all polynomials of degree less than or equal to $n$ over $\Bbb{R}$ ?

Comment: What are your attempts?

Comment: Yes i mean the vectorspace of all polynomails of degree less than or equal to n over R

Answer (score 2):

The map $p(X) \mapsto p(X+1)$ is a bijective linear transformation $\Bbb{R}_n [X] \to \Bbb{R}_n [X]$.

The set in question is the image of the canonical basis of $\Bbb{R}_n [X]$ and so is a basis of $\Bbb{R}_n [X]$.

Answer (score 1):

The set $B:=\{1, 1 + X, (1 + X)^2 , . . . , (1 + X)^n \}$ contains $n+1$ elements. Since $ \dim R_n[X] =n+1$, you have only to show that $B$ is linearly independent. To this end let $a_0,a_1,...,a_n \in \mathbb R$ such that

$0=a_0+a_1(1+X)+...+a_n(1+X)^n$.

Define $q(X)$ by $q(X)=a_0+a_1X+...+a_nX^n$ and $p(X):=q(1+X)$. Then we have $P(X)=0$ for all $X$.

Conclusion ?

Comment: What would be the conclusion